# Finding the most recent date in from all dates in Drools object

Tags: drools, drools-planner, drools-flow

How can I find the most recent date among all joining dates in a Drools object?

My rule is something like this:

```
declare RecentDate
      dates : java.util.Date
end

rule "insert_dates"
      when
       //reading dates from back end
       Employee($date : dateOfJoining, $name : name, salary > 10000)
       then
       insert(new RecentDate($date))
end
```

Now I would like to find the most recent employee based on dateOfJoining. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to, given an employee, make sure that there is no other with a higher date:

```
declare RecentDate
      dates : java.util.Date
end

rule "insert_dates"
when
  //reading dates from back end
  Employee( $date : dateOfJoining, $name : name, salary > 10000)
  not Employee (dateOfJoining > $date)
then
  insert(new RecentDate($date))
end
```

The rule above only works on the case you have all your `Employee` facts in your session before you execute `fireAllRules()`. If this is not the case, you can try to initially insert a `RecentDate` with a null date and then compare each `Employee` against it and update it accordingly:

```
rule "Init RecentDate"
when
  not RecentDate()
then
  insert new RecentDate(null);
end

rule "update_dates"
when
  Employee( $date : dateOfJoining, $name : name, salary > 10000)
  $d: RecentDate ( date == null || date < $date)
then
  modify ($d){
    setDate($date)
  }
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have tried in this way. But RecentDate() object containing all dates after inserting .  I have created another rule to print date in RecentDate(), But it is printing all dates for employees salary > 10000. My requirement is to find only the most recent date.

Comment: Hmmm... How are you inserting your facts and when are you calling `fireAllRules()`? Are you calling  `fireAllRules()` after each `Employee` you insert?

Comment: I've added a second way that is not affected by the order of insertion and execution of the facts and rules.